# How to get client IP in webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux

I used to call HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() to get client ip.

I'm wondering how can I get it via ServerWebExchange.

My best guess is:

```
  serverWebExchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way to achieve that.
Note that if you’d like to support Forwarded or X-Forwarded-* HTTP request headers, this is something that needs to be configured at the server configuration level.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest`,

```
String remoteAddress = serverHttpRequest.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
```

as it sad in doc: `.reactive.ServerHttpRequest`
**represents a reactive server-side HTTP request.**

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServerHttpRequest.html

Comment: ez, here you are, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServerHttpRequest.html
@DavidBuck

Answer (score 0):

You could also add `org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest` as parameter to `@RerquestMapping` annotated method and got IP address from it:

```
@GetMapping("/myPath")
public void someMethod(ServerHttpRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();)
}
```